# Compare Expected value against actual value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am trying to do a data comparison. I have the expected result in an excel file and I want to compare the expected result against the Actual result.  Actual result is obtained by running a query against a DB
My excel looks like this:

[image: Excel]

I am using pandas to read from excel and write to a dataframe.

```
    def get_src_query_metadata(cursor, sql_query):

         cursor.execute(sql_query)
         columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
         cursor.rowfactory = lambda *args: dict(zip(columns, args))
         data = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
         return data

    def main():
        df = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx")
        testcases = df['Testcase'].values
        queries = df['Query'].values
        expected_result = df['Expected Result'].values
        for i in range(0,len(df)):
            testcase_nm = testcases[i]
            _expected = expected_result[i]
            _JobDict = get_src_query_metadata(cursor, queries[i])
            _actual_result_init= _JobDict.get('COLUMN1')
            _actual = _actual_result_init[0]
            if (str(_expected)) == (str(_actual)):
                print(testcase_nm , "--> Test Passed")
            else:
                print(testcase_nm , "--> Test Failed")
```

My Output:
Test1-->Test Passed
Test2-->Test Failed

Test1 is passing since my expected and actual are having the value 7000 .
However Test2 is failed. This is my expected and Actual result.
Expected:
5345
5346
5347
actual:5346

The error happens since I have this below code. How do I make sure I get all the values without the index to match my expected result. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: please put your fullcode.

Comment: @JasarOrion please don't ask for _full code!_ Instead, we prefer that people post a [mre]. A MRE helps people focus on the part of the code that _actually needs fixing_ instead of reading line after line of irrelevant code.

Comment: yes your right . sorry . my bad

Comment: How wrong would it be to suggest abusing unittest subtest for this? It would certainly output helpful differences and which test failed.

Comment: I want my actual results without index value. That is the reason I tried having  
`_actual = _actual_result_init[0]` . However for some queries , I may get multiple values . How do I capture all the values is my question .

Answer (score 0):

```py
k=0
for column in range(len(LIST[k][0]))  # to get the columns 
      k+=1 
#increment k every time to ensure you get the first number of each column in the list
```

if the data is represented as:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

etc.